# NodeJS: Azure functions with a `serviceBusTrigger` is giving `InvalidResourceName` error when trying to list blobs with `listBlobsFlat`

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-servicebus-queues

I have created two Azure functions, one with `HTTPTrigger` and another with `ServiceBusTrigger`. When I try to list blobs from `HTTPTrigger` function, with `listBlobsFlat` method of Azure Javascript SDK, I was able to list without any problem. When I try the same thing with `ServiceBusTrigger` function, I have an error saying `Error in servicebus trigger RestError: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidResourceName</Code><Message>The specifed resource name contains invalid characters`. I can see the queue message that triggered azure function. It is fine. The `ServiceBusTrigger` function works fine with other activities like uploading a Storage Account, etc.

My container name is `datasources`. It has only one file named `twitter.csv`. What am I missing?

Edit: Both the Functions use same function from a helper. I am using `"@azure/service-bus": "^7.0.0-preview.2"` and `"@azure/storage-blob": "^12.1.2"`.

```
export const listAllBlobs = async (container: string = containerName): Promise<any> => {
  const blobServiceClient = await BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(creds.connectionStr)
  const containerClient = await blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(container);
  const blobs = []
  try {
    for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {
      blobs.push(blob)
    }
    return blobs
  } catch(err) {
    throw err
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and include the source code for both functions?

Comment: Could you please provide your function code?

Comment: Is that you use typescript language to create function?

Comment: Yes, does that matter? I tried with plain JS too. The error is same.

Comment: @Murali Ok. I see.  I will do a test.